# How to fan-gate mobile Facebook users?

Tags: facebook, mobile, facebook-apps

As you all know, mobile users can't access the page tab apps. I've googled around and found some methods to enhance the mobile user experience. But no method to keep the fan-gating feature working (besides third-parties like Shortstack). The best solution now seems to send the user to a page and on the page either send them to the FB page tab (desktop/tablet users) or a mobile friendly external page (mobile users). However, external page don't allow you to fan-gate. Is there no solution, or have I just not found it yet?

Comment: One could argue that "fan-gating" and "enhancing user experience" shouldn't be in the same sentence :)

Comment: @Lix There is some truth in that statement, but I'm trying to find a balance. A balance which results in more likes, but an acceptable user experience :)

Comment: Fan-gating is only allowed on page tabs apps so there is no way to do it on mobile.